# What was used for symmetric message authentication before HMAC was invented?

Tags: mac, cbc-mac, history

Currently, Carter Wegman MACs are popular. Before that, HMAC was popular. What was popular before HMAC? Was it CBC-MAC? Something else?

I know about [NIST FIPS 113 "Data Authentication Algorithm"](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/113/archive/1985-05-01) which was [CBC-MAC with DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Authentication_Algorithm) as the block cipher, from 1985. Was that actually used? Even if yes, what was used before 1985? When did people start using a MAC, and how did that early MAC work? (I think Enigma didn't have a MAC, right?)

Comment: The question title asks about HMAC, but the body mentions CBC-MAC. Is this international?

Comment: @MichaelSnook is it clearer after the edit?

Comment: Looks better, yes